# Is a timing side channel attack effective when the leaked information is related to the result of a hash?

Tags: hash, format-preserving, timing-attack

I'm writing a function to act as a cryptographic hash of a number within a range that returns another number of the same range. The catch is that the result needs to have certain properties. I run a simple test for these properties and call the function recursively if the test fails. Naturally this raises a red flag for a timing attack, however, the test is performed on the result of a hash only. Everything preceding the hash takes exactly the same amount of time regardless of input.

My question is, is this a harmful leak of information?
Here's the function in question.

```
def numhash(num, maxnum):
    num = sha256(str(num)).hexdigest() # calculate sha256 of string version of number
    num = int(num, 16) % maxnum # convert this to an integer and mod it by the top bound of the range (exclusive)
    if bin(num).count('1') % 2: return numhash(num + 1) # check for an even number of 1 bits in the number, reject and try again if true. This is where the timing issue is caused
    return num
```

Note: I'm aware of the slight bias towards lower results and high collision rate. This is acceptable.

Comment: Much worse problem than side channel attack: when iterating, it is with `num` set to `(int((sha256(str(num)).hexdigest()),16)%maxnum)+1` rather than the apparently intended `num+1`, which is from a set of at most `maxnum` values, and we are not sure that this terminates. $\;$ If the criteria is even parity, why not generate the low-order bit from the top ones, avoiding iteration, and recursion? Evenness for odd `maxnum`requires care, though. $\;$ Also: `str(num)` is quite likely to have a timing side channel. Just don't code crypto **primitives** in high-level languages !

Comment: I would argue that it is high level APIs that are the problem rather than high level languages, since e.g. `printf` or even `itoa` has similar issues as `str`. Plus, don't code primitives, period, if you can help it.